# Error of Unexpected class while encode/decode an NSArray with NSSecureCoding

Tags: ios, objective-c

### Background

We have multiple classes that conform to `NSSecureCoding` protocol.

```
@interface ClassA : NSObject <NSSecureCoding>
// ...
@end

@interface ClassB : NSObject <NSSecureCoding>
// ...
@end
```

We notice that `NSArray` also conforms to `NSSecureCoding`. Therefore, we try the following.

For encoding:

```
NSArray* array = ...
[archiver encodeObject:array forKey:@"AirdropDataKey"];
```

For decoding

```
NSArray* array = [unarchiver decodeObjectOfClass:[NSArray class] 
                                          forKey:@"AirdropDataKey"];
```

And I get this following error message.

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', reason: 'value for key 'NS.objects' was of unexpected class 'ClassA'. Allowed classes are '{(
> NSArray
> )}'.'

Anybody could explain why and whether it is possible to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`NSCoder` provides an additional method [`decodeObjectOfClasses:forKey:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCoder_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSCoder/decodeObjectOfClasses:forKey:), where a set of expected objects could be passed. This allows to decode nested structures.

Just pass a set with the `NSArray` and your `ClassA` and `ClassB` class:

```c
NSSet *classes = [NSSet setWithObjects:[NSArray class], [ClassA class] ,[ClassB class], nil];
NSArray* array = [unarchiver decodeObjectOfClasses:classes forKey:@"AirdropDataKey"];
```

Answer (score 0):

For decoding use below [method](https://developer.apple.com/Library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCoder_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSCoder/decodeObjectForKey:) and check:-

```
 - (id)decodeObjectForKey:(NSString *)key
```

Comment: Why can't we use `NSSecureCoding` but have to `NSCoding`?